# SMF to phpBB3 bbcode trouble

Tags: bbcode, phpbb3

Hi for the last 3 years my site has used SMF2 the time came to move away from it i wont go into detail on that but anyway Ive converted all of it to phpBB3 everything works fine until you see a quote from the old system because there are differences it fails to parse the quotes for example

[quote="MitchaP":1ru0x694][/quote:1ru0x694] is what phpBB3 would look like
but smf looks like [quote="MitchaP"][/quote]

I have tried to modify the bbcode.php file with no luck here is what i have so far BTW my regex is starting level if even that :)

```
    $this->bbcode_cache[$bbcode_id] = array(
                    'str' => array(
                        '[/quote:$uid]' => $this->bbcode_tpl('quote_close', $bbcode_id),
          '[/quote]' => $this->bbcode_tpl('quote_close', $bbcode_id)
                    ),
                    'preg' => array(
                        '#\[quote(?:=&quot;(.*?)&quot;)?:$uid\]((?!\[quote(?:=&quot;.*?&quot;)?:$uid\]).)?#ise' => "\$this->bbcode_second_pass_quote('\$1', '\$2')",
          '#\[quote(?:=\"(.*?)\")?\](.+)\[/quote\]#ise' => "\$this->bbcode_second_pass_quote('\$1', '\$2')"
                    )
                );
```

Comment: I would just like to add whoop i did my first code block on stack overflow :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find in includes/bbcode.php

```php
foreach ($bbcode_ids as $bbcode_id)
{
    switch ($bbcode_id)
    {
```

and replace case 0: with below

```php
        case 0:
            if($this->bbcode_uid > 0)
            {
                $this->bbcode_cache[$bbcode_id] = array(
                    'str' => array(
                        '[/quote:$uid]' => $this->bbcode_tpl('quote_close', $bbcode_id)
                    ),
                    'preg' => array(
                        '#\[quote(?:=&quot;(.*?)&quot;)?:$uid\]((?!\[quote(?:=&quot;.*?&quot;)?:$uid\]).)?#ise' => "\$this->bbcode_second_pass_quote('\$1', '\$2')"
                    )
                );
            }
            else
            {
                $this->bbcode_cache[$bbcode_id] = array(
                    'str' => array(
                        '[/quote]'  => $this->bbcode_tpl('quote_close', $bbcode_id)
                    ),
                    'preg' => array(
                        '#\[quote(?:=&quot;(.*?)&quot;)?\]((?!\[quote(?:=&quot;.*?&quot;)?\]).)?#ise'   => "\$this->bbcode_second_pass_quote('\$1', '\$2')"
                    )
                );                  
            }
        break;
```

[phpbb](/questions/tagged/phpbb)[phpbb3](/questions/tagged/phpbb3)

Comment: will this match both versions while i wait for reply ill add and test :)

Comment: Tested for both, I actually edited the database BLOB and removed the UID to get it show that it works.

Comment: no still no luck but it looks like it should work it just does not no idea why i have pasted a copy of a post here http://pastebin.com/SGWnf0pZ just so if u need to you could test

Comment: i just dumped the $this->bbcode_uid and its empty so its defo adding that to the array, Edit: yep defo in the array

Comment: but if i dump the $username, $quote in bbcode_second_pass_quote i get no output

Comment: it seems the bitfield is not seeing the quote but yet yours works

Comment: im totally head blagged on this

Comment: ah ha viewtopic line 1795 says if ($row['bbcode_bitfield']) and obviously does not have one

Comment: can i ask what the rules of bitcode are could it be anything for instance if i updated all the rows with a random bitcode would that matter or would it cause errors

Comment: from dumping the vars past to bbcode_second_pass there is no bitfield a little further down it has an if !bitfield return

Comment: I pasted your version of bbcode. Which returned errors http://test.damienkeitel.com/bbcode.php.txt has the correct version with my edits

Comment: yea theres still no bitfield so its allways gonna hit this
        if (!$this->bbcode_bitfield)
  {
   // Remove the uid from tags that have not been transformed into HTML
   if ($this->bbcode_uid)
   {
    $message = str_replace(':' . $this->bbcode_uid, '', $message);
   }

   return;
  }

Comment: weird, I have it working on mine http://test.damienkeitel.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1&p=43#p43

Comment: added the > 0 to the first if statement to make it correctly change the right bbcode

Comment: i found out why had to add this to the viewtopic.php

Comment: if(!$row['bbcode_bitfield']) {
    $message_parser = new parse_message($message);
    $message_parser->parse_bbcode();
    $row['bbcode_bitfield'] = $message_parser->bbcode_bitfield;
    $row['bbcode_uid'] = '';
  }

Comment: BTW thanks for all your help on this it had me stumped :) BTW your facebook login will u be making that public and also would it still have the ability to use normal registration aswell as FB login

Comment: Also do you plan on making a google one :) i would make them myself but with everyhting else would be the last thing on the list

Comment: We shouldn't be discussing this here. Head over to http://www.damienkeitel.com for more info.